Chatbot skipping parts of resume (using Ollama's gemma2:2b model)
I'm working on an AI chatbot that's supposed to respond based on my resume. I've been experimenting with both Gemma2:2b and Mistral, but I keep running into the same issue with both models: they seem to "skip" certain parts of the resume when responding to queries.
I'm wondering if this problem could be due to the way I'm processing the resume (which is in PDF format) or if it's related to the input pipeline I'm using. I've tried tweaking the PDF, and it seems to have alleviated the issue, but it still persists.
Relevant parts of my code:
pdf_handling.py
import argparse
import os
import shutil
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.schema.document import Document
from get_embedding_function import get_embedding_function
from langchain_chroma import Chroma

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--reset", action = "store_true", help = "Reset the database.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.reset:
        print("✨ Clearing Database")
        clear_database()

    documents = load_document()
    chunks = split_documents(documents)
    add_to_chroma(chunks)

def load_document():
    document_loader = PyPDFLoader("Resume.pdf")
    return document_loader.load()

def split_documents(documents: list[Document]):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size = 800,
        chunk_overlap = 80,
        length_function = len,
        is_separator_regex = False,
    )
    return text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

def add_to_chroma(chunks: list[Document]):
    db_directory = "my_chroma_data"  
    db_path = os.path.join(db_directory, "chroma.sqlite3")  

    os.makedirs(db_directory, exist_ok=True)
    
    db = Chroma(
        persist_directory=db_directory,  
        embedding_function=get_embedding_function()
    )

    chunks_with_ids = calculate_chunk_ids(chunks)

    existing_items = db.get(include=[]) 
    existing_ids = set(existing_items["ids"])
    print(f"Number of existing documents in DB: {len(existing_ids)}")

    new_chunks = []
    for chunk in chunks_with_ids:
        if chunk.metadata["id"] not in existing_ids:
            new_chunks.append(chunk)

    if len(new_chunks):
        print(f" Adding new documents: {len(new_chunks)}")
        new_chunk_ids = [chunk.metadata["id"] for chunk in new_chunks]
        db.add_documents(new_chunks, ids=new_chunk_ids)
    else:
        print("✅ No new documents to add")

def calculate_chunk_ids(chunks):

    last_page_id = None
    current_chunk_index = 0

    for chunk in chunks:
        source = chunk.metadata.get("source")
        page = chunk.metadata.get("page")
        current_page_id = f"{source}:{page}"

        if current_page_id == last_page_id:
            current_chunk_index += 1
        else:
            current_chunk_index = 0

        chunk_id = f"{current_page_id}:{current_chunk_index}"
        last_page_id = current_page_id

        chunk.metadata["id"] = chunk_id

    return chunks

def clear_database():
    db_path = "my_chroma_data/chroma.sqlite3"
    if os.path.exists(db_path):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.dirname(db_path))  
        print(f"✨ Database at {db_path} has been cleared.")
    else:
        print("⚠️ No database found to clear.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

chatboy.py
import os
from langchain_chroma import Chroma  # Updated import
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms.ollama import Ollama
from get_embedding_function import get_embedding_function

PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """
You're roleplaying as Maximiliano López Montaño, based on what the resume says.

This is the resume: {context}

---

Answer the question based on the above context: {question}
"""

def main():
    print("Welcome to the chatbot! Type 'exit' to quit.")
    
    while True:
        query_text = input("You: ")
        
        if query_text.lower() == 'exit':
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        
        response = query_rag(query_text)
        print(f"AI: {response}")

def query_rag(query_text: str):
    embedding_function = get_embedding_function()

    persist_directory = "my_chroma_data"
    db_path = os.path.join(persist_directory, "chroma.sqlite3")

    if not os.path.exists(db_path):
        print("⚠️ Database not found. Please run pdf_handling.py to create the database.")
        return "No data available."

    db = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embedding_function)

    results = db.similarity_search_with_score(query_text, k=5)

    context_text = "\n\n---\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc, _score in results])
    prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
    prompt = prompt_template.format(context=context_text, question=query_text)

    model = Ollama(model="gemma2:2b")
    response_text = model.invoke(prompt)

    formatted_response = f"{response_text}"
    return formatted_response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Where the issue might lie? What improvements can I make?
I can also share the PDF if necessary.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I cannot give a comment yet so i will be posting it as an answer.
If your resume.pdf have images containing this "skipped parts" then it will not be read, you will need to pdf > image(s) > OCR before you can get the full text of the document.
